# search_path in structure.sql file gets modified by rails db:migrate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, postgresql-9.6, dbmigrate, apartment-gem

Everytime I run `rake db:migrate` on my project the `db/structure.sql` changes and I'm happy. Unfortunately the changes are not only additions to my table but also something strage in explicitly using our `tenant` keyword and `extensions` keyword.

```
db/structure.sql | 20278 ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 file changed, 9565 insertions(+), 10713 deletions(-)
```

This is part of my interesting diff after I migrate:

```
-CREATE FUNCTION _final_median_function(anyarray) RETURNS double precision
+CREATE FUNCTION extensions._final_median_function(anyarray) RETURNS double precision
```

and here is an example for table:

```
-SET search_path = at, pg_catalog;
-CREATE TABLE advert_all_clicks (
+CREATE TABLE at.advert_all_clicks (
```

Postgres 9.6.10 (also tested and it happens in 10.+)
Multitenancy is done using [apartment](https://github.com/influitive/apartment)

Does anyone has any idea why this is happening? Could't find too much and I'm battling with this for a while.

Edit: In connection to my problem I found [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-prepare.html) but it applies to postgres < 9.3

Answer (score 1):

This is strange but I'm going to respond just in case someone else has the same issue.

If you're on a project that uses `db/xx.sql` file then if you open it, on very first lines you'll see the versions of `pg_dump` and `postgres` which were used to generate this dump.

In order to successfully restore from a dump or have this file `db/xx.sql` clean while running `db:migrate` you must have the same exact version installed. It's not working with a different major/minor/release (must be the exact same)

In my case first lines are looking like:

```
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 9.6.5
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 9.6.5
```

I tried installing 9.6.10 (which is current postgresql@9.6) and other different versions. It continue to mess with my file until I compiled exactly 9.6.5 from source.

Couldn't find an explanation for this and I don't see changes in the 9.6.x changelogs.

Soon I'll create a homebrew-tap and have it here as an example.